# How to display csv file in AngularJS HTTP in a table?

Tags: angularjs, http, html-table, import-from-csv

The data in the CSV file shows up in the browser if I don't use ng-repeat, but it is cluttered and unorganized. I'd like to put it in a table, but i'm not sure the code. The below code doesn't work, but it is my best guess.

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
        <td ng-repeat='field in area'>{{field}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
        <button class="button" ng-click="click()">Button 1</button>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

                $scope.area= function() {               
                $scope.click = function() {

                    $http.get("test.csv").then(function (response) {
                        $scope.field =response.data;

                    });
                };
                };

            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can't interpret csv format directly.
You need a converter first (Ex: convert-csv-to-json )
Install it via npm

```
npm install convert-csv-to-json --save
```

In your script

```
// $scope.field =response.data;

let csvToJson = require('convert-csv-to-json');

let json = csvToJson.formatValueByType().getJsonFromCsv(response.data);
console.log(json) // You can do whathever you want
```